# Filing jointly and wife as father-in-law dependent

Tags: united-states, taxes, marriage, dependents

I'm an independent contractor attempting to figure my estimated tax payments for 2014, and I have the following situation: I'm getting married in June and plan to file jointly for 2014. Will my new father-in-law still be able to file with my wife as a dependent if I do file jointly?

I don't want to take away from his cut in taxes, as he will have supported her almost entirely up until I take over in June.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for her father to claim your wife as a dependent, she must only be filing a joint return with you to recoup any witholding that she had.

> Joint Return Test
>
> You generally cannot claim a married person as a dependent if he or she files a joint return.
>
> Exception.   You can claim an exemption for a person who files a joint return if that person and his or her spouse file the joint return only to claim a refund of income tax withheld or estimated tax paid.

From [Publication 17](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch03.html#en_US_2013_publink1000170866)

Since you will be married to her on the last day of the year, you are considered married for that entire tax year.